# Concurrency in .net for a function

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

I have the following code being run in multi-threading business logic:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var biz1 = new Biz { Some = 1, Value = "a" };
            var biz2 = new Biz { Some = 2, Value = "b" };
            var foo = new Foo();

            //thread 1
            new Task(() => foo.Run(biz1)).Start();
            //thread 2
            new Task(() => foo.Run(biz2)).Start();
            //more threads here for other Biz objects....

            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    public class Biz
    {
        public int Some { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        public void Run(Biz biz)
        {
            //base on the biz object do some task here

        }
    }
}
```

The `biz` object is NOT being changed at anytime during threading

Questions:

- Is `foo.Run` thread safe?
- Is it better to instantiate individual `Foo` object to run each `Biz` object (the `Run` is the only function within `Foo`)?

Comment: Well is `Foo` being changed by `Run`?

Comment: It's not possible to say if foo.Run is thread-safe if we don't know what it actually does

Comment: @Jon Skeet, the `Foo` is NOT being changed by `Run`

Comment: So do Biz objects contain data only and Foo object contain only methods?

Comment: @ken2k right, I agree. The actual business logic fairly complicated. It's calcuation against the `biz` object.

Comment: So there's no shared state being changed here? If so, that sounds safe enough...

Comment: @Jon Skeet, so far that's the case.

Comment: Seems a strange pattern that you are splitting the data from methods in this fashion I'm sure there is a valid reason. Remember though that now Foo is entirely dependant on the structure of Biz. If any of the properties of Biz are changed then Foo will also need changed.

Comment: @TheKingDave, I agree on the dependant issue. And you are right, that patten is based on the actual requirement. Thanks for your kind reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - Is foo.Run thread safe?

It sounds like your Foo.Run() is safe, it depends on what other data is accessed of course.

> - Is it better to instantiate individual Foo object to run each Biz object (the Run is the only function within Foo)?

Assuming it is safe, ie it does not use any instance data of Foo, `Run()` could and should be `static`. This would at least convey a better message to the reader.

```
public static class Foo
{
    public static void Run(Biz biz)
    {
        //base on the biz object do some task here

    }
}
```